# Change value inside Future(success(Some(List(BN)))

Tags: scala

I have a class as

```
case class BN[A] (val BNId: Long, score: Double, child: A)
```

and a database as BnDAO

```
class BnDAO(...) {
  def readAsync(info : scala.Long)(implicit ec : scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext) : scala.concurrent.Future[scala.Option[scala.List[BN]]] = { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

During my function of calling BnDAO to retrieve BN for set of ids, I want to change the result BN's score according to a `Map[InfoId: Long, score: Double]`

Here is my current code

```
val infoIds = scoreMap.keys.toSet
val futureBN = infoIds.map {
      id =>
        val curBN = interestsDAO.readAsync(id)
//curBN is now "Future(Success(Some(List(BN))))"
        val curScore = scoreMap.get(id)
        //how to change curBN's score with curSocre?
    }
```

Thank you!!

//Thank you for Allen's answer. Based on his answer. Is it possible to create a Set of Future[Option[List[BN]]] and a Map of Long to List[Long] (infoId -> List[BNId]) within one traverse.

Comment: the id inside BN is not same as the id calls BnDAO, so it cannot be done outside this mapping?

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if it is what you want.

Comment: Sorry, there was mistake in answer. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I was not sure what you meant, so I created two answers. Pick the one that you want.

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
val ids = scoreMap.keys.toVector
val futureBN = ids.map { id =>
  val curBNFut = interestsDAO.readAsync(id)
  val v = curBNFut.map(opt => opt.map(l => 
    id -> l.map(e =>
      scoreMap.get(e.id).map(escore => e.copy(score = escore)).getOrElse(e)
    )
  )
}
val mapResultFut = Future.sequence(futureBN).map(m =>
  m.flatMap(identity).toMap
)
val mapResult = Await.result(mapResultFut, 5.seconds)
val setFut = futureBN.map(fut => fut.map{opt => opt.map{case (id, l) => l }}).toSet
```

or

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
val ids = scoreMap.keys.toVector
val futureBN = ids.map { id =>
  val curBNFut = interestsDAO.readAsync(id)
  val v = curBNFut.map(opt => opt.map(l => 
    id -> l.map(e =>
      scoreMap.get(id).map(escore => e.copy(score = escore)).getOrElse(e)
    )
  )
}
val mapResultFut = Future.sequence(futureBN).map(m =>
  m.flatMap(identity).toMap
)
val mapResult = Await.result(mapResultFut, 5.seconds)
val setFut = futureBN.map(fut => fut.map{opt => opt.map{case (id, l) => l }}).toSet
```

The difference is in the input to scoreMap.get

I am not sure which one you want.

Post a comment if there is anything wrong. Make sure to test my answer, so that it is what you want.

Comment: if I want to have a return type of a Map of Long to List[BN], how do I change the code? Or is it possible to retrieve one Map of Long /*ids*/ to List[Long] /*BN.id*/ and a Set of Future[Option[List[BN]]] within one traverse? (read DAO only once for each id)

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify. So you want one Map of Long to List[Long]. And one Set of Future[Option[List[BN]]]?

Comment: For the Set of Future[Option[List[BN]]] are you sure you just want a Set of Futures? That seems odd. You are throwing away the id information. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: yes, if that's possible be done within one traverse.

Comment: I can give you a Future[Map[Long, List[Long]]] that you will have to block on to obtain Map[Long, List[Long]]. That is the first item. The second item is a Set of Future[Option[List[BN]]]. Is that correct? I'm going to start writing the solution. Let me know if there's anything wrong.

Comment: I have update the question, so it will be more clear! Thank you so much